# Build Failure: How to use Pyenv to install Python 3.8.3 on macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1?

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I tried using the command `pyenv install 3.8.3` to install Python 3.8.3 but got a build failure error pictured below.

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.0.1 using python-build 20180424)

[image: Build Failure Error]

Does anyone know how to make the build successful on macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.8.3 is far too old to support macos 11

At the time of writing, the current 3.8.x release [3.8.7 has only partial support for big sur](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-387/) (it will build and run, but it lacks some system library support).  Full support is planned in python 3.8.8

Comment: 3.8.8 will be it then when developing with Chalice on Big Sur until Chalice moves to 3.9

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i use path python to install all versions. this command resolve all problems:

> pyenv install --patch 3.6.8 <<(curl -sSL
> [https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch%5C?full_index%5C=1))

In case you need another version, just change 3.6.8 for your version.

Answer (score 1):

I am successfully running python 3.8.3 on mac intel (Ventura 13.5)

In order for this to work I had to:

- use homebrew zlib instead of xcode
- use non-standard compiler
- use a patch to support apple specific build issues

```
brew install gcc@11 

LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib" CC=$(which gcc-11) pyenv install 3.8.3 --patch < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like it's Mac issue. Not sure what was actually happened, but it worked after I uninstall the CLT then reinstall.

Below is the steps I have done:

1. Uninstall current CLT:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

2. Remember to install "Xcode" from the App Store if not.
3. Run `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` then update pyenv in Homebrew should make things work.

Answer (score -3):

If you have brew installed you can use it to install python3.8. Try using:

```
brew install python@3.8
```

Also, you can use `python3.8 -m virtuanenv` to create a virtual environment

Comment: This is good advice, but the question is specifically about pyenv. The user might have a specific use case that requires pyenv.